# Boost mapped_file or file_mapping

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I'm creating a file-based Octree of a Point Cloud in order to manage filters on really big file (that can't be stored in ram). The bottleneck of this method, so far, is the I/O of the leaves (because I often have to write, rewrite files and read files ...)
So I would like to use memory mapped file technique to make it faster, and I heard about Boost.
But when I search for tutorials, I have seen 2 techniques :
One use `#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>`
and the other
`#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>`.

In my casae, I will have to write really often entires vectors of 3D points in file, then get all informations in these files and recreate vectors from them. A lot of I/O operation with probably a lot of files.
I was wondering which one I have to use? In which case I have to use one instead of the other?

Thanks!

P.S : [Is there a difference between boost iostream mapped file and boost interprocess mapped file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531652/is-there-a-difference-between-boost-iostream-mapped-file-and-boost-interprocess) I have seen this post, but it doesn't help me for my particular problem.

Comment: Did you do any benchmarks? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of these, however:

- Using only [`boost::iostreams::mapped_file`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file) object you get a file mapped into memory with array interface. It doesn't get any simpler than that. You can also use [`boost::iostreams::stream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) decorator to attach `std::iostream` interface to the mapped file.
- Whereas [`boost::interprocess::file_mapping` requires using `boost::interprocess::mapped_region`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_creating_shared_memory_segments) to map the `file_mapping` into memory. This method is more flexible as it allows to map parts of the file (rather than the entire file) with different access permissions but it is also more complex.

Comment: I heard with my eyes that memory mapping would not be really efficient if the goal was to read entire file... Is that so?

Comment: @RaphSchim File mappings primarily avoid copying memory between the kernel and the user space. Don't take their word for their dubious claims, demand benchmarks.

Comment: I will!! :) 
And for my request here, since I only have to do basic operation with my file, the `boost::iostreams::mapped_file` will be sufficient !

Comment: Do you know where I can find a good tutorial? All the tutos I read about didn't contain enough information on what's happening really !

Comment: @RaphSchim From SO rules: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract 
opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: Even in comment?   
But ok ^^ I will find it myself then! :) Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The link labelled `boost::interprocess::file_mapping` actually points to a page about sharing memory generally rather than the detailed documentation for the class, which is fine except it points to the wrong location within the page: it points to the heading about `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object`. Here's a fixed link: [`boost::interprocess::file_mapping`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file)